# how to test authService with jasmine?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, ionic4, angular8

i am trying to unit test my login page using jasmine and karma but am always having this error 'Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://beta-lp.biodymanager.com/fr/api/login_check", found none.' when i want to make sure that the method login is calling the post function that calls 'https://beta-lp.biodymanager.com/fr/' + SERVICE_LOGIN

this is my spec file

```
describe('LoginPage', () => {
  let component: LoginPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginPage>;
  let loginBtn: HTMLButtonElement;
  let eye : HTMLIonIconElement;


  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginPage ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule , 
        RouterModule.forRoot([]),
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'tabs/dashboard', component: LoginPage },{ path: 'tabs/home', component: LoginPage }]),
 ReactiveFormsModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        IonicModule,
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,


      ] ,
      providers : [LoginPage,InAppBrowser, HTTP, Device, Globalization, AngularDelegate, CommonService ,
      AuthService,ModalController,Network,RestApiService,{
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useValue: '/'
      }]
     })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    loginBtn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('ion-button'); 


  });

   it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();  
   });
 describe('login method', ()=> {

      const value : IUser =({
        email   : 'emnas@gmail.com',
        password: 'Zeynep' 
      });

      it('test manager validity from API ',inject( [AuthService, HttpTestingController],(service : AuthService,http : HttpTestingController)=> {      

 spyOn(service,'login').and.returnValue(Observable.of({email : 'emnas@gmail.com' , password : 'Zeynep'}));


       service.login(value).subscribe(result =>{

          expect(result).toBeDefined();
          expect(result).toEqual(value),
          console.log(result);
       });

       const req = http.expectOne("https://beta-lp.biodymanager.com/fr/api/login_check");
       expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
       expect(req.request.body).toEqual(value);     

       req.flush({user: {email :'emna@gmail.com'}, token: 'xxx'});
```

this is my authservice

```
export class AuthService extends RestApiService {

  login(body) {
    return this.post(SERVICE_LOGIN, body, false, false);
  }
```

the restApiService

```
export class RestApiService {
// constructor

post(url, data: any, withAuth?: boolean, withLang?: boolean): Observable<any> {

    if (typeof withAuth === 'undefined') {
      withAuth = true;
    }
    if (!withAuth) {
      this.clearAuthHeader();
    }
    return new Observable<any>((observer) => {
      this.setAuthorizationHeader().then((authorization) => {
        this.setLocale().then((language) => {
          let apiUrl = this.locale + url;
          if (!withLang) {
            apiUrl = url;
          }
          if (this.device.platform === 'Android' || this.device.platform === 'iOS') {
            this.globalization.getPreferredLanguage().then(res => {
              console.log('current language', res);
              const code = res.value.split('-')[0];
              if (this.locale === '') {
                this.locale = code;
              }

              if (withLang) {
                apiUrl = this.locale + url;
              }
              console.log('Post request - apiUrl:', apiUrl);
              const body = JSON.stringify(data);
              let host = '*';
              if (!withAuth) {
                host = '-';
              }
              this.http.post(appConfig.getBaseUrl() + apiUrl, body, this.http.getHeaders(host)).then((response) => {
                console.log('addNewMeasurement - response.data: ', response.data);
                observer.next(JSON.parse(response.data));
                observer.complete();
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('addNewMeasurement - error: ', error);
                observer.error(error);
                observer.complete();
              });
            }).catch(e => console.log(e));
          } else {
            if (!withAuth) {
              this.clearAuthHeader();
            }
            if (this.locale === '') {
              this.locale = 'en';
            }
            if (withLang) {
              apiUrl = this.locale + url;
            }

            const body = JSON.stringify(data);

            this.httpClient.post(appConfig.getBaseUrl() + apiUrl, body, { headers: new HttpHeaders(this.headers) }).subscribe((result) => {
              observer.next(result);
              observer.complete();
            }, (error) => {
              observer.error(error);
              observer.complete();
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

this is appconfig file which contains the url api

```
testBaseUrl: 'https://beta-lp.biodymanager.com/'         
 export const SERVICE_LOGIN: string = 'api/login_check';
```

**am i doing somthing wrong? thank you in advance**

Comment: Remove `LoginPage` from `providers` array, it is not needed there. As for why it's not finding the HTTP request, I am not sure. I would mock all external dependencies of `LoginPage` though and test `AuthService` to do its job correctly. If its doing its job correctly, it should be mocked in `LoginPage`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
const req = http.expectOne("https://beta-lp.biodymanager.com/fr/api/login_check");
```

by this

```
 const req = httpMock
.expectOne(req => req.method === 'POST' && req.url === 'https://beta-lp.biodymanager.com/fr/api/login_check');
```

Or you can check *expectOne* overloads, there are many ways to call this function

https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController#expectOne

Under expectOne() section click on '**3 overloads**'

Comment: i tried before those three methods but it's vain, i  already tried this method but i always get error Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match by function: ", found none.
but i think that the problem is that the service which we use extends another service RestApiService and the method post which we use in this service is declared in RestApiService.
is it true what we are doing in this spec page?

Comment: @EmnaSouilem Sorry for the late reply, can you share the code of RestApiService ?

Comment: i added it in the question

Comment: I'm not seeing the constructor where you set 'this.http', are you using httpClient or httpModule ? In both cases, I see you are not importing the httpModule or injecting the Http service in TestBed module declaration

Comment: this is the constructor of RestApiService (
    public http: HTTP,
    public httpClient: HttpClient,
    public device: Device,
    public commonService: CommonService,
    public globalization: Globalization
  ), in my spec file i imported HttpClientTestingModule

Comment: I don't understand why you use  sometimes http and then httpClient. anyways I don't see the souce of the problem, what I would do in this case I'll right another services with httpClient and simple post request to another public endpoint and test it in the spec file for a debug purpose, if it works means a problem in the service otherwise it's in the spec, so you should continue the debuging by rewriting the file and test.

Comment: i didn't write the code, I am just testing it, so i can't touch the code of the service only if the problem is related to the service then I can contact the developer, I got the same error either in another test of another page.